# GooglePlayGame services not working properly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I imported Google Play Games Services plug in

then implement it using some tutorials

But

Still can't figure **Achievement** and **Leader Board** not showing

log in fine

But I don't understand why these are not working

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class LeaderBoardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LeaderBoardController instance;

    public const string leaderBoardId = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQAQ";

    // Achievements ID
    public const string score5 = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQAg";
    public const string passTheScore30 = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQAw";
    public const string unlockTheGreenBird = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQBQ";
    public const string unlockTheDawnLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQBg";
    public const string becomeAcenturian = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQBw";
    public const string unlockTheRedBird = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQCA";
    public const string unlockTheMountainsLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQCQ";
    public const string unlockTheLakeLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQCg";
    public const string unlockTheSpringLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQCw";
    public const string unlockTheFarmLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQDA";
    public const string unlockTheWinterLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQDQ";
    public const string unlockTheEveningLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQDg";
    public const string unlockTheDarkLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQDw";
    public const string unlockTheRainyLevel = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQEA";
    public const string becomeTheUltimateFlappy = "CgkIlY-bvcoNEAIQEQ";

    void Awake ()
    {
        MakeSingleton ();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();

    }

    void OnEnable ()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += this.OnLoadCallBack;
    }

    void OnLoadCallBack (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
    {
        ReportScoreLocal (GameController.instance.GetHighScore ());
        ReportProgressLocal (GameController.instance.GetHighScore ());
    }

    void OnDisable ()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= this.OnLoadCallBack;
    }

    // making C# script singleton
    void MakeSingleton ()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void ConnectGooglePlayGames ()
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowAchievementsUI ();
        }
        else
        {
            Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) =>
            {

            });
        }
    }

    public void OpenLeaderBoard ()
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderBoardId);
        }
    }

    void ReportScoreLocal (int score)
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            Social.ReportScore (score, leaderBoardId, (bool success) =>
            {

            });
        }
    }

    void ReportProgressLocal (int score)
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            if (score >= 5 && score < 30)
            {
                Social.ReportProgress (score5, (double) score, (bool success) =>
                {

                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another good way to understand how Achievement and Leaderboards work is to follow the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) with the [Type A Number github sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples). Make sure to integrate the GPGS in your app by providing the correct Application ID and the package name in both your app and the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you update Android Setup after add achievement? Or do you republish changes in Google play services dashboard?

Also, change

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowAchievementsUI ();
```

to

```
Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
```

and change

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderBoardId);
```

to

```
Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
```

For more information, see these links:

[Google Play Games Services Tutorial (Unity) #1 - ACHIEVEMENTS and LEADERBOARDS](https://youtu.be/5Ae8GeRmdH0)

[Achievements & Leaderboard - Google Play Services - Subway Skater - 23](https://youtu.be/XN29LTFtk3c)

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: I just new to google play services and this is my first code. I will try the changes and let you know

Comment: Sure. Good luck

Comment: I only find another link that may helps you. Please check [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/leaderboard-setup-for-android-in-unity)

Comment: my main problem was I needed to initialize before make it  active. not it works. thanks

Comment: You should add these lines to your answer **PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
  PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance (config);**

Answer (score 2):

To make my code working I have to change some codes along with **@Ehsan Mohammadi's** suggestions.

first of all making changes to start method

```
void Start ()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
}
```

to

```
void Start ()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance (config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
}
```

And

changing the following statements

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowAchievementsUI ();
```

to

```
Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
```

And

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderBoardId);
```

to

```
Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
```

After making these changes my code just works fine.